# Embed PDF into modal window IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf

I’m using fancy box to embed a pdf into a modal, code below:

```
<object data='pdf/document.pdf#view=FitH&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0' type='application/pdf' width='360px' height='510px'>
    <embed src='pdf/document.pdf#view=FitH&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0' type='application/pdf' width='360px' height='510px' />
</object>
```

This works fine in all browsers except in IE9 and 10 where the modal will load the PDF the first time, but when I close the modal and open it again I get a grey box where the PDF should be. In IE8 the PDF does not load at all.

I thought about using an iFrame, but I need to display inline content alongside the PDF, i.e.; PDF on the left, with inline text and image on the right.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following alternatives to display PDF embedded in HTML page:

- [PDFObject](http://pdfobject.com) script to embed PDF.
- [PDF.js viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) (client-side javascript PDF viewer, see the [online demo](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)) but notice it requires IE 9 to IE 11 as minimum depending on PDF;